# createReadStream() in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, fs, ionic-native

I am trying to upload a photo from my app to Facebook.

I have tried the following to get the image stream using Node JS for POC, which works fine.

```
let imageData = require('fs').createReadStream(path);
```

I want to achieve the same in my Ionic 3 app but the problem is that **fs** isn't available in Ionic. I have tried using the following functions of @ionic-native/file but those didn't help.

```
readAsText(path, file)
readAsDataURL(path, file)
readAsBinaryString(path, file)
readAsArrayBuffer(path, file)
```

What is the best way to get the createReadStream(path) functionality in Ionic 3?

Comment: What code are you using to send the picture to Facebook ?

Comment: FB.api(“me/photos”, “post”, {source: imageData})

Comment: Are you using plugin or web facebook api ? How do you get the path of your image data ?

Comment: That I am getting through ionic-native image picker. There is no problem with the path as I can display the images in my app.